# Jui Slider removing key events

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, yii-components

I have a issue not sure how complicated it is but I have been unsuccessful in finding a solution and I have spent some considerable time troubleshooting and Googling resolutions.

Here is my issue, I have a jQuery UI Slider on my page.

I insert a new value using Ajax and it basically rebuilds the Slider.

All that works perfect. The problem is any key bindings I had are removed. (I know the solution for this).

The problem comes where I remove a mouse event prior by changing it at the root of the widget.

I cannot just recall this after the Slider is rebuilt, I don't understand why but it just doesn't work as it did on the first page load.

Here is my code to disable the Slider click tracker.

```
// Disable the mouse tracking for ui-slider-handle(s)
$.widget('ui.slider', $.ui.slider, {
    _mouseCapture: function(e) {
        return (!$(e.target).is(this.element)) ? this._super(e) : false;
    }    
});
```

Nothing in there is specific to the slider itself since this changes the slider widget itself.

Just to be clear I am only looking at removing a certain binding mouse event to the Jui Slider.

The above code works at doing that, but it won't work once I rebuild the slider with a new value via Ajax.

```
$('#slider').unbind();
```

The above unbind() function removes all bindings and makes the slider not functional, just visual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding 2 lines in my framework as framework specific code for Yii.

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['*.js'] = false;
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['*.css'] = false;
```

It doesn't allow for the scripts to get reinitialized on the page.